# Query Amazon EC2 status health with API

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

It is possible to get the EC2 health messages via their API? The health status is presented here: http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An RSS feed is available of these dashboard, eg for [CloudFront](http://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/cloudfront.rss) and [Ec2 tokyo](http://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/ec2-ap-northeast-1.rss).
All these are available on http://status.aws.amazon.com/ right hand side of each service url there is RSS icon. This can be used programatically to do whatever you to do?.

Comment: Does it archive every entry, so that if I want to check for a service health on a specific past date, I just have to browse the output and look for an event around it ?
This may look obvious, but I never used RSS feeds, and the zone I checked (cloudwach, eu-central) had a quite empty output, so I guess I'd better ask.

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently launched a [Health API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/health-api.html) which is used to get this sort of information without resorting to RSS parsing. This can be paired up with [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) to get notifications pushed to you without resorting to polling.